# New to React, questions/benefit/disadvantage about using all JS instead of HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am starting to play around in React and I noticed that the simple app I am making is all in JS. My html page is only an empty body tag!

So I had a few questions because I am new to this framework.

Is my whole app supposed to be essentially all JS?

If it's not supposed to be all JS, when do I decide that something belongs in my html file vs creating it as a react component in JS?

What are the benefits / disadvantages that my html is in all JS?

Am I supposed to set up my server to compile the JS to html to serve html re: Server Side Rendering to maximize performance benefits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React brings a new way of seeing things: components.

There are two approaches when using React:

- **AMD** (Asynchronous Module Definition): your javascript files are loaded under demand; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition and in http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html
- **CommonJS**: in this case your app is bundled into only one file (or a few 'chunck' files) - it seems that people have been preferred this way because the app is loaded only one time and it goes to the server only for loading and writing data (i.e. JSON); it helps in reducing charges over the server;

The page is really an empty body tag.... hehe

But with some considerations:

Please take a look at **React-Router** (or even Angular Route if you use AngularJS):

To move from the current 'page' (view) to a new page, the browser's URL is 'pushed' (changed) without going to the server and the entire new page is mounted according to that URL. This is made by React-Router or Angular Route.

Yes, you are supposed to make your server to output html: you can search for Isommorphic Javascript if you want your client html to be mounted dynamically (useful when you need search engines like Google to scan your page) More info at: http://isomorphic.net/ and this can help you: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-react-isomorphic-javascript-why-it-matters/

I know there is a lot of new technologies to study, but it's worth...

A little tip I can give you is looking for "Flux". It's a design pattern that helps structuring your application better, that allows you to scale and grow it.

You can take a look at webpack and babel too. Great stuff!

Hope this helps you.